# Ajax call to php script sending values from multiple checkbox form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, checkbox

I have a form with plenty of check-boxes. Check-boxes are divided to categories, each of which has about 20 check-boxes. Categories are size, color, etc... but to simplify this, I just explain the size category which has 20 check-boxes like this:

```
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" name="size[]"><label class="checkboxvalue">size 1</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="size[]"><label class="checkboxvalue">size 2</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="size[]"><label class="checkboxvalue">size 3</label>
  .
  .
  .
  <input type="checkbox" name="size[]"><label class="checkboxvalue">size 20</label>
</form>
```

I want to Ajax call to the php script and retrieve the relating records from database which have the checked sizes (and of course the chosen color, pattern, design, ...).
I wondered if there is chance to send this many of data using arrays, because I have 10 categories and 20 check-boxes in each, resulting in a number of 200 parameters and I think this is too many.
If I could use an array it could be something like passing 10 arrays.
After hours of googling, I discovered that I should have my check-boxes like this `<input type="checkbox" name="size[]">` instead of this `<input type="checkbox" name="size1">` , but I am stuck in the JavaScript part. I used this:

```
<script>
  $("input[name='size[]']").on( "click", function getValues() {
    $("input[name='size[]']").map(function() {
    return this.checked;
    }).get().join(",");
  });
</script>
```

This returns a list of comma-separated values for check-boxes like `true,false,true,true,...,false,false` according to the size category check-boxes, but I don't know how to send them to the php script as an array. should I use the JSON formatting? how can I access them on php script? this is my ajax:

```
function ShowResult(size,color,pattern,design,application,producer) {
  var xmlhttp;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }else{
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
      document.getElementById("main").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","filter.php?size[]="+size+"&color[]="+color+"&pattern[]="+pattern+"&design[]="+design+"&application[]="+application+"&producer[]="+producer,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

As a complimentary portion of my question, what is the best way to minimize the transferred data to the script? is it good practice to send `0 or 1` instead of `false or true` for the checked state of check-boxes in an array? Maybe, that's better to send just the index of those sizes with checked values. Is there a better way to accomplish this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you choose is to some degree based on how you evaluate 'best'. In this case, I'd use three major criteria:

1. Low bandwidth
2. Clear code (semantically correct and easily understandable)
3. Easy code (code that is easy to write, debug and maintain)

Given your second code sample, it seems apparent that you're using jQuery. The first thing that I would do is replace your AJAX method with a call to [`$.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) or [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). This will simplify your code and make it easier to maintain.

The next thing I'd do is modify things to use the [checked selector](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/), which will streamline the process of getting the list of checked values. Something like this:

```
var checkedValue = $("input[name='size[]']:checked").map(function() {
    return Number(this.value);
}).get();
```

In order for this to work, you'd need to set the `value` property of your `<input>` tag. Something like this:

```
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" name="size[]" value="1"><label class="checkboxvalue">size 1</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="size[]" value="2"><label class="checkboxvalue">size 2</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="size[]" value="3"><label class="checkboxvalue">size 3</label>
  .
  .
  .
  <input type="checkbox" name="size[]" value="20"><label class="checkboxvalue">size 20</label>
</form>
```

This will produce an array containing the values of the checked boxes. For example, if sizes 1, 5, 7, and 20 were checked you would get `[1,5,7,20]`.

Next, for sending it to PHP you basically have two options: CSV or JSON. Since the data you're working with is so simple, there isn't really much reason to use one over the other, so I'll show how to do both!

CSV JS:

```
var sizeList = $("input[name='size[]']:checked").map(function() {
    return Number(this.value);
}).get().join(",");

$.get("filter.php", {
        'sizeList': sizeList // I'm averse to any non-alphanumeric characters in URLs; you could use size[] if you prefer
    }, function(responseData) {
        $("#main").html(responseData);
    }
);
```

CSV PHP:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['sizeList'])) {
    $sizes = explode(",", $_REQUEST['sizeList']);
} else {
    // handle error
}
```

JSON JS:

```
var size = $("input[name='size[]']:checked").map(function() {
    return Number(this.value);
}).get();

var sizeList = JSON.stringify(sizes);

$.get("filter.php", {
        'sizeList': sizeList // I'm averse to any non-alphanumeric characters in URLs; you could use size[] if you prefer
    }, function(responseData) {
        $("#main").html(responseData);
    }
);
```

JSON PHP:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['sizeList'])) {
    $sizes = json_decode($_REQUEST['sizeList']);
} else {
    // handle error
}
```

My personal recommendation is to use CSV unless you anticipate the format of your data changing to be more complex than a simple list of numbers. CSV is great for simple tabular data, but not for more complex formats. Meanwhile, JSON is (almost) overkill for a simple numerical list, but really shines if you want to transmit complex data objects.

EDIT: Updated method. It appears that `.val()` does *not* return an array when there are multiple elements returned by the selector. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YFhRK/) for an example. I've used the method suggested by Arash in the comments.

Comment: I really appreciate this, as you have spent much time on this complete answer. I will try to implement it and accept your answer in minutes. Thanks a lot again!

Comment: Yes! like a charm, with a little correction using `var sizeList = $("input[name='size[]']:checked").map(function(){return this.value;}).get().join(",");` to generate the javascript array. It would be great if you consider ths correction in your answer. thanks a lot J. David Smith

Comment: I tested it in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YFhRK/) and found that `.val()` does not behave as I expected (or, apparently, as the people who reviewed your edit expected). I've updated my answer to use a slightly edited version of your method (I chose to convert the values to numbers).